# How to insert (change values) matrix in matrix? Python (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

For example, I have a matrix:

```
[ [1 2 3 4 5],

  [6 7 8 9 10],

  [11 12 13 14 15],

  [16 17 18 19 20],

  [21 22 23 24 25] ]
```

I want to insert [ [-1 -1 -1], [0 5 0] ] in some position, like:

```
[ [1 2 3 4 5],

  [6 7 8 9 10],

  [11 -1 -1 -1 15],

  [16 0 5 0 20],

  [21 22 23 24 25] ]
```

Comment: That's not inserting, that's changing existing values. What have you tried?

Comment: It's not unclear how would you define "some position". Reading up on [indexing/slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#) should help.

Comment: I have a matrix with pixels of the image (frame t-1). In the next frame, I found blocks that correspond to the offset (motion). Now I'm trying to replace the pixels with the values of these blocks in order to restore the frame. I tried: k = -1
    l = -1
    for i in range(to_x, to_x+4):
        k = k + 1
        for j in range(to_y, to_y+4):
            l = l + 1
            t_rec[i][j]=im_block[l][k]

Comment: That last comment probably should be edited into the question itself. Also, the word "replace" (in the comment) seems to be the word you want instead of "insert".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example, I would say you are trying to *replace* or *modify*
part of the existing array rather than *insert* an array.

You could use [basic slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) to get a view of the part of the array you want to overwrite,
and assign the value of that slice to a new matrix of the same size
as the slice.
For example:

```
>>> x=np.matrix([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
>>> x
matrix([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]])
>>> x[1:3,1:4]=np.matrix([[-1,-2,-3],[-4,-5,-6]])
>>> x
matrix([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5, -1, -2, -3],
        [ 9, -4, -5, -6],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

In general, to describe a submatrix of `m` rows and `n` columns with its upper left corner at row `r` and column `c` of the original matrix,
index the slice as `x[r:r+m,c:c+n]`.

Answer (score 2):

Use numpy insert!
Here is an example from the numpy reference at scipy:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]])
>>> a
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
>>> np.insert(a, 1, 5)
array([1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
>>> np.insert(a, 1, 5, axis=1)
array([[1, 5, 1],
       [2, 5, 2],
       [3, 5, 3]]
```

Read more here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html

Answer (score 0):

This method take the matrix m, and replace the elements with array n starting from row r, column c

```
def replace(m, n, r, c):
    i = 0
    if len(n) + c > len(m[r]):
        return
    for each in n:
        m[r][c] = n[i]
        c += 1
        i += 1
```

you have to check the index boundaries for the matrix